# C++11 lvalue, rvalue and std::move()

Tags: c++, c++11, overload-resolution, rvalue

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void test(int& a) {
    cout << "lvalue." << endl;
}
void test(int&& a) {
    cout << "rvalue" << endl;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a = 1;
    int&& b = 2;
    test(a);
    test(1);
    test(std::move(a));
    test(b);
}
```

which outputs:

```
lvalue.
rvalue
lvalue.
lvalue.
```

`std::move()` and `int&&` are rvalue references, I wonder why `test(std::move(a))` and `test(b)` output `lvalue`? Is it related with signature matching and function overloading?

Comment: What compiler are you using? The output should be `lvalue rvalue rvalue lvalue`.

Comment: @TartanLlama I would guess MSVC, which is always buggy.

Comment: @TartanLlama, I use Mac, the compiler should be LLVM's clang.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The output *should* be:

```
lvalue.
rvalue
rvalue
lvalue.
```

There is a very important distinction to be made between expressions which are rvalues and expressions whose type is an rvalue reference. The type of `b` is an rvalue reference to `int`, but the expression `b` is an lvalue; it is a variable, you can take its address. This is why the final line of output is `lvalue` rather than `rvalue`. In order to change it to an rvalue, you should call `std::move` on it:

```
test(std::move(b));
```

Comment: Cool, you're right. The IDE I used ignores the "-std=c++11" option with the underlying command, such caused my output to be like what I've posted. I've tested the code in Terminal, if compiled without the "-std=c++11" option, then undesired output is given with warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You can read this article, which explains it very well [Universal References in C++11](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers). Also it worth mentioning that now these references called *forwarding references*.

In your case you have

```
void test(int& a); // lvalue reference overload
void test(int&& a); // rvalue reference overload
```

Second case allows you to implement move semantics or perfect forwarding inside the function. Though first one also allows it, only you need to use `std::move` which will turn its value to rvalue.

```
test(a);
test(1);
test(std::move(a));
test(b);
```

- `a` has a name, so applying move semantics to it tacitly would be dangerously confusing and error-prone because the thing from which we just moved, is still accessible on subsequent lines of code.
- `1` has no name, you can take the address of it, so it is  an rvalue.
- `std::move(a)` by using `std::move` you turn this to rvalue, you should remember it when you use `a` next time.
- `b` the same as with `a` - it has a name, you can take the address of it.

Some examples of lvalues and rvalues:

```
// lvalues:
//
int i = 42;
i = 43; // ok, i is an lvalue
int* p = &i; // ok, i is an lvalue
int& foo();
foo() = 42; // ok, foo() is an lvalue
int* p1 = &foo(); // ok, foo() is an lvalue

// rvalues:
//
int foobar();
int j = 0;
j = foobar(); // ok, foobar() is an rvalue
int* p2 = &foobar(); // error, cannot take the address of an rvalue
j = 42; // ok, 42 is an rvalue
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10890990)

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi I've taken your advice to heart :)