# How to deal with const T& and T&& instantiating to the same signature?

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

Basically I want to provide construction from const lvalue versions and rvalue reference versions:

```
    transform_iterator(const Functor& f, const Iterator& it) :
            functor(f),
            iterator(it)
    {}

    transform_iterator(Functor&& f, Iterator&& it) :
            functor(f),
            iterator(it)
    {}
```

From what I know, the rvalue reference version is not universal references. Despite that, on this call site:

```
template <typename InputIt, typename OutputIt>
std::pair<InputIt, OutputIt> sliding_average(InputIt first, InputIt last,
                    const typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type window_length,
                    OutputIt d_first)
{
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type;
    auto divide = [&window_length](const value_type& value)
    {
        return value / window_length;
    };

    auto iterator = shino::transformer(divide, d_first); //transform_iterator<Functor, Iterator>

   shino::sliding_window(first, last, iterator, window_length);
                                       //^^ pass by value
```

compiler says that rvalue reference version ends up being const lvalue reference version.

For completeness, here is the call site of the `sliding_average`

```
sliding_average(v.begin(), v.end(), window_length, output.begin());
```

where both `v` and `output` are vectors of int and doubles, and `window_length` is `std::size_t`.

When I remove the const lvalue version, code compiles and works correctly.

Also, this code compiles without problem with both of the constructors:

```
std::vector<std::string> v{"23", "25", "27"}; //just random numbers
std::vector<int> output(v.size());

auto string_to_int = [](const std::string& x)
{
    return std::stoi(x);
};

auto conversion_iterator = shino::transformer(string_to_int, output.begin());
```

**Question:** How to fix it?

Comment: Where is `transform_iterator` being called with an *rvalue*?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, updated.

Comment: You're still not passing any *rvalue*. `iterator` is an *lvalue*, just like `d_first`. Did you forget an `std::move`?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, may be it happens as a result of `shino::transformer<>()`? There is no other place where I pass by rvalue.

Comment: Btw, this is not the idea of a move constructor.

Comment: @FloHe: where was "move constructor" mentioned?

Comment: Sorry, I think my title mislead readers. I might ask another question soon, but the thing I don't understand is that why ADL even considers rvalue reference based constructor?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: It was defined, wasn't it?

Comment: @Incomputable: there's no ADL in action here

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, thanks for uncovering a lot of gaps in my knowledge. I'll probably need to reread Effective Modern C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think that your understanding of *lvalue*s and *rvalue*s is not correct.**

You're not invoking `transform_iterator::transform_iterator` with an *rvalue* anywhere in the code you've posted.

---

```
auto iterator = shino::transformer(divide, d_first);
//                                         ^^^^^^^
//                                         lvalue
```

To invoke the *rvalue reference* overload, you need an *rvalue*! `std::move` can be used to cast `d_first` to an *rvalue reference* - example:

```
auto iterator = shino::transformer(divide, std::move(d_first));
//                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                         rvalue
```

---

The same applies to the code you added in your edit:

```
shino::sliding_window(first, last, iterator, window_length);
//                                 ^^^^^^^^
//                                 lvalue
```

You probably want:

```
shino::sliding_window(first, last, std::move(iterator), window_length);
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                 rvalue
```

---

Relevant questions:

- [**"C++11 lvalue, rvalue and std::move()"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784755/c11-lvalue-rvalue-and-stdmove)
- [**"What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

Answer (score 1):

In

```
auto iterator = shino::transformer(divide, d_first);
```

You are always going to call the const lvalue reference overload of the function.  The reason is that `d_first` is a named variable.  That means it is an `lvalue` even if it was passed into the function as an rvalue.  If you want to make a named variable a rvalue you need to use `std::move` like

```
auto iterator = shino::transformer(divide, std::move(d_first));
```